# Delay time only for "ñ" key

Tags: keyboard, spanish

I have a Spanish keyboard, with Win 10.
Since a couple of weeks ago, whenever I press the <kbd>ñ</kbd> key, I have to keep it depressed for the character to be typed.
This delay is similar to that for repeating characters, but for the first.
This is annoying, and it only happens with <kbd>ñ</kbd>.

It happens with the laptop keyboard and an external keyboard as well.

**How can I solve this?**

**Related**

1. https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/delay-on-the-n-key.618153/ (with no answer)

Comment: Can you try an external keyboard? If that works, the first keyboard likely needs to be replaced

Comment: @John - That's the first thing I had tried that and forgot to post it. OP updated.